# Error 424 when copying a table in access

Tags: excel, vba

I'm ridiculously new to SQL.  I'm trying to write a bit of code from Excel VBA to reach out to an Access DB file, drop a table, and copy data from another table in access to that first table based on the value of one of the columns.

So far, I'm just trying to copy one table to another and I'm getting 424: Object required.  What am I missing?

```
Sub Update()

Dim cnnAccess As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstAccess As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnnAccess = New ADODB.Connection
Set rstAccess = New ADODB.Recordset
cnnAccess.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};Dbq= (path to file)\(nameofDB).accdb;Uid=ID;Pwd=PASSWORD;"
cnnAccess.Open

cnn.Execute "Drop Table tbl_daily"  <-- Error hits on this line
cnn.Execute "SELECT * From tbl_TMD where date = 42856 INTO tbl_daily FROM 
tbl_TMD"

End Sub
```

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You never set `cnn`  I think you intended on having that line read, `cnnAccess.Execute`.  I'd recommend using `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your modules.  You'll have the same problem on the next statement.

Comment: if you drop a table you can't insert into it (the table/object is deleted).  Are you sure the error isn't on the next line? where you would need to [select into](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192059.aspx)? (or maybe there's more than 1 error).  I agree I don't see the cnn object set.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two scripts below.  Also, remember to set a reference to Microsoft DAO x.xx Object Library

```
Sub DAOCopyFromRecordSet(DBFullName As String, TableName As String, _
    FieldName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: DAOCopyFromRecordSet "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", "FieldName", Range("C1")
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset
Dim intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFullName)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(TableName, dbOpenTable) ' all records
    'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & TableName & _
        " WHERE " & FieldName & _
        " = 'MyCriteria'", dbReadOnly) ' filter records
    ' write field names
    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        TargetRange.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next
    ' write recordset
    TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you want more control with the data import, you can customize the macro below:

```
Sub DAOFromAccessToExcel(DBFullName As String, TableName As String, _
    FieldName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: DAOFromAccessToExcel "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", "FieldName", Range("B1")
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset
Dim lngRowIndex As Long
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFullName)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(TableName, dbOpenTable) ' all records
    'Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & _
        TableName & " WHERE " & FieldName & _
        " = 'MyCriteria'", dbReadOnly) ' filter records
    lngRowIndex = 0
    With rs
        If Not .BOF Then .MoveFirst
        While Not .EOF
            TargetRange.Offset(lngRowIndex, 0).Formula = .Fields(FieldName)
            .MoveNext
            lngRowIndex = lngRowIndex + 1
        Wend
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```